# Detect Specific Words on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my String:

```
var str1 = '@hello, world how are you. I @am good';
```

Now I want to split `@` prefixed worlds like @hello, @am etc to be stored in an array.
Desired output will be

```
var str2 = [@hello, @am];
```

can anyone guide me.

Comment: Do you have an attempt?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: The way you asked the question is not exactly as what stack overflow is expected. That's why you have got more negative votes. You should have try different ways, you should have browse for related answers / questions and you have to post the question with those details (whatever you have tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, i add comment for easy understand this code

```js
var str = '@hello, world how are you. I @am good';
str = str.split(' '); // split text to word array
str = str.filter(function(word){
  return word.includes('@'); // check words that using @
}).map(function (word) {
  return word.replace(/[^a-zA-Z^@ ]/g, "") // remove special character except @
});
console.log(str) // show the data
```

Answer (score 1):

With a simple regex

> `\B@\w+/g`

without a function :

```
var str1 = '@hello, world how are you. I @am good';
console.log(str1.match(/\B@\w+/g));
```

with a function :

```
getMatchedStrings("@hello, #world how are you. I @am good");

function getMatchedStrings(input){
    var re = /\B@\w+/g;         
    var specials = [];
    var match;
    while(match = re.exec(input)){
        specials.push(match[0]);
    }
    console.log(specials)
}
```

You may try more regex here : 
https://regex101.com/r/rBuMrY/1

Output:

```
["@hello", "@am"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str1 = '@hello, world how are you. I @am good';
var reg = /(?:^|[ ])@([a-zA-Z]+)/;
var str = str1.split(" ");
//console.log(str.length);
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (reg.test(str[i])) {
    //your code to store match value in another array
    console.log(str[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex, I am not really good at it but just a try

```js
var str1 = '@hello, world how are you. I @am good';
var str2 = str1.match(/@(.+?)[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g).map(function(match) { return match.slice(0, -1); });
console.log(str2);
```